# How to split string in View in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, model-view-controller, view, split

In my View I have this condition:

```
@if (User.Identity.Name == "abc")
{
   ... do this!
}
```

How can I split this string "User.Identity.Name" in View (in MVC) so I can create new condition, something like this:

```
string last = User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
if (last == "this")
{
   ... do this!
}
```

thanks.

Comment: you can split it using `Split("some string")`

Comment: i need to find dot "." and last index of string, so i need to find string after dot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
@{

    var temp= User.Identity.Name.Split('.');

    if (temp[temp.Count() - 1] == "this")
    {

    }

}
```

or if  **"."**  will be only one time in that string then you can hardcode like this:

```
@{

    var temp= User.Identity.Name.Split('.');

        if (temp[1] == "this")
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: this is great Ehsan, but how to implement this in View?

Comment: simple the way you do in action same way in view

Comment: you just need to create razor block to write c# code like `@{ write statements here  }`

Answer (score 1):

see below example , which finds last word of a string after last dot in it.

```
String str = "abc.def.xyz";

String last = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
System.out.println(last);
if(last.equals("something")){
    //do this
}

else{
    //do this
}
```

here `last` comes as `xyz`